# getting the productID from the SKU with the BrightPearl api

Tags: brightpearl

The BrightPearl API lets programmers change product prices by using a productID. I only have the SKUs for the products that I want to update. Is there a way to use the BrightPearl API to look up individual productID by using individual SKUs? 
A less appealing option is to build a dictionary with SKU keys and productID values for all of the products. Is there a way, via the API, to get product information (including SKUs and productIDs) for all of the products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://ws-use.brightpearl.com/public-api/".$BP_ACCOUNT_ID."/product-service/product-search?SKU=".$SKU;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    
array('Accept: application/json', "brightpearl-app-ref:".$brightpearlAppRef, "brightpearl-account-token:".$brightpearlAccountToken));
$r = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$productID = $r->response->results[0][0];
```

The /product-service/product-search option will return alot of data in JSON format, which includes the productID. BrightPearl warns about duplicate SKUs when creating records, but it allows them, so consider checking the JSON response for multiple records before using the productID to update a record.